# Websphere MQ message doesnot backout to Input Queue

Tags: java, message-queue, ibm-mq, mq, backout

Have a message in Websphere MQ. Have read the message and I am trying to backout the message to Input Queue. Retry threshold not yet reached. Does the MQ message automatically put into Input Q when exception occurs? This is my code:

```
MQQueueManager qm = new MQQueueManager("");
MQQueue q = qm.accessQueue("");
MQMessage message = new MQMessage();
q.get(message);
System.out.println("Retry Count"+ message.backoutCount);
throw new NullPointerException;
```

Will the above code put the message to Input Queue again? In this case, it is not putting message back to Input Queue. Message is lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your message can only be backed out if it was part of a transaction to begin with. Your code doesn't use transactions.

Take a look at the MQGMO options, `MQGMO_SYNCPOINT` and `MQGMO_SYNCPOINT_IF_PERSISTENT` (search for the string `MQGMO_SYNCPOINT` in the below two links).

[MQ Java Classes CMQC constants](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJavaClasses/com/ibm/mq/constants/CMQC.html)

[MQ API description of MQGMO_SYNCPOINT - applicable to all languages](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q096780_.htm)

And also the commit() and backout() methods on the `MQQueueManager`:

[MQQueueManager class](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJavaClasses/com/ibm/mq/MQQueueManager.html)

and suggest you read this general purpose explanation of transactions

[Committing and backing out units of work](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q026790_.htm)

Comment: Yes..It works now..But I want to get clarified on one thing..If an exception occurs while processing the msg, will the msg is backed out to Input Q for re-processing for number of pre-configured time? If it reaches the threshold then the msgs moved to Backout Queue? In my case, the same thing happens. But once I close the application, all messages are moved back to Input Queue from Backout Queue. This is happens for again the same retry count number of time..Get confused here.. Pls help

Comment: If you have a backout queue and backout threshold defined on your input q, then some interfaces (not basic MQI) will only allow a particular message to be backed out so many times before they move it to the backout queue. Your description sounds like your never committed a transaction? Can you perhaps uodate your question (or raise a new one) with your code using syncpoints?